# How to add empty space between columns using SingleChildScrollView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

And I use a column in which there are 2 more columns and align them using the `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` property so that there is an empty space between them. But on small screens, I don't have enough space for all the widgets, so I decided to add a SingleChildScrollView to allow scrolling. But I ran into a problem that then the empty space between the columns disappears. Tell me how to add scrolling and keep empty space between columns?

**code**

```
Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  const Divider(
                    color: constants.Colors.greyMiddle,
                    height: 1,
                  ),
                  _createDrawerItem(
                      SvgPicture.asset(
                        constants.Assets.profile,
                      ),
                      'My Profile'),
                  const Divider(
                    color: constants.Colors.greyMiddle,
                    height: 1,
                  ),
                  _createDrawerItem(SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.profile),
                      'My Preferences'),
                  const Divider(
                    color: constants.Colors.greyMiddle,
                    height: 1,
                  ),
                  _createDrawerItem(
                      SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.dashboard),
                      'Dashboard'),
                  const Divider(
                    color: constants.Colors.greyMiddle,
                    height: 1,
                  ),
                  _createDrawerItem(
                      SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.wallet), 'Wallet'),
                  const Divider(
                    color: constants.Colors.greyMiddle,
                    height: 1,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              // const Spacer(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 19),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    _createDrawerItem(SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.invite),
                        'Invite & Earn !',
                        horPadding: 11),
                    _createDrawerItem(
                        SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.settings), 'Settings',
                        horPadding: 11),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

**added SingleChildScrollView**

[image]

**without SingleChildScrollView**

[image]

Comment: Interesting situation. Might be impossible to do like you want, but I'm  not sure. Maybe you could just wrap the top column in a SingleChildScrollView, that way the bottom two items are always in view, and the rows above are scrollable for smaller screens.

Comment: Yes, as I can rather impossible. But I'll try another option. By the way, thanks also for your idea, I'll try to use it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Column(
  children: [
    ....
  ]
),
SizedBox(
  height: 100,//custom height
),
Column(
  children: [
    ....
  ]
),
```

OR

```
Column(
  children: [
    ....
  ]
),
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:100),
    Column(
      children: [
        ....
      ]
    ),
),
```

Comment: And if I need to make the empty space always change depending on the screen size. That is, if the screen is small - there is less empty space, if the screen is large - there is more empty space?

Comment: to change height dynamicly, you can use Expanded, and it takes all the space it can take. But, using scroll view make it impossible. But if you wrap your scrollView with SizedBox than it can be managable.

Answer (score 3):

If you use SingleChildScrollView , However (

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetwen
```

) Can't use.

Now you use

```
 SizeBox(),
```

Using Height will not be a responsive issue

Comment: thanks for you valuable answer it's very help full for me.